# Can Teamcity display real name instead of SVN username on the front page?

Tags: configuration, teamcity

On the front page of Teamcity 6, it shows the svn username of the person who made change in that build.

At my work, these names are not very descriptive, for example mine is "cc75657"

Is there any way to configure Teamcity to show the real person's name instead of this svn username? It would make it much easier for people to know who made which changes.

Comment: Looks like there is already a raised issue for this: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-13559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that in TeamCity, several users may configure their VCS username to the same value, so the actual mapping from VCS username to TeamCity user is 1 to N.
Also, see http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-13560

The only thing I can suggest is to file your request to TeamCity's tracker.